# How can I delete irregular chunks of words in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, web-crawler

It is reproducible example.

```
df2 <- data.frame(Num = c(1,2,3), Comment = c('nick       comment12021.12.01      nickn comment2222021.12.02       nickname333       commennnnt222021.12.01', 'nick       comment12021.12.01      nickn comment2222021.12.02       nickname333       commeeeent222021.12.01','nick       comment12021.12.01      nickn      comment2222021.12.02       nickname3333333       comment22021.12.01') )
```

```
Num           Comment
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      Tom    comment1~   Jay     comment2     Yun    comment 3 ~
2      Tim    comment1~   Cristal     comment2~      Lomio    comment3~
3      Tracer  comment1~   Teemo   comment2~      Irelia   comment3~
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have a dataframe with 2 columns and many rows.
These are comments I got from crawling a website. However, since it is a very dynamic website, I had no choice but to get nicknames and comments from multiple people at once.

I want to delete nicknames from this irregular chunk of text and create a word cloud with only comments. But I can't think of a way to delete only the nickname.
The length of nicknames and comments is irregular, so I can't do it the way I know.

Comment: Do you have any additional separators or structure in the data, eg everything is put in " or maybe some tags from the scraping. If you dont have this additional separators, it might be impossible to achieve what you are looking for. 
If possible, can you share an excerpt of the data or mock some data.

Comment: @David Yes, It has separators '         ' Seven space bar. For example, "Nickname 'Seven space bar' comment12021.12.01 'Seven space bar' Nickname2 'Seven space bar' comment22021.12.01 'Seven space bar' Nickname3 'Seven space bar' comment32021.12.01"

Comment: Note that your comment column is not always separated by seven spaces, you might have to reduce the regex to `" {3}"` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fixed separator (like exactly seven spaces (`" {7}"` using regular expressions) you mentioned in your comments), you can do the following:

```
dd <- data.frame(
  id = 1:3,
  comment = c(
    "Tom       comment1~       Jay       comment2~       Yun       comment3~",
    "Tim       comment1~       Cristal       comment2~       Lomio       comment3~",
    "Tracer       comment1~       Teemo       comment2~       Irelia       comment3~"
  )
)


extract_comments <- function(comments) {
  lapply(
    comments, 
    function(x) {
      sp <- strsplit(x, " {7}")[[1]]
      sp <- trimws(sp)
      ppl <- seq(1, length(sp), by = 2)
      data.frame(
        ex_person = sp[ppl],
        ex_comment = sp[ppl + 1]
      )
    }
  )
}

dd$extracted <- extract_comments(dd$comment)

tidyr::unnest(dd, extracted)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#>      id comment                             ex_person ex_comment
#>   <int> <chr>                               <chr>     <chr>     
#> 1     1 Tom       comment1~       Jay     ~ Tom       comment1~ 
#> 2     1 Tom       comment1~       Jay     ~ Jay       comment2~ 
#> 3     1 Tom       comment1~       Jay     ~ Yun       comment 3 
#> 4     2 Tim       comment1~       Cristal ~ Tim       comment1~ 
#> 5     2 Tim       comment1~       Cristal ~ Cristal   comment2~ 
#> 6     2 Tim       comment1~       Cristal ~ Lomio     comment3~ 
#> 7     3 Tracer       comment1~       Teemo~ Tracer    comment1~ 
#> 8     3 Tracer       comment1~       Teemo~ Teemo     comment2~ 
#> 9     3 Tracer       comment1~       Teemo~ Irelia    comment3~
```